# Preload nested stack in react-navigation 5.x tab

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have a simple React Native app with 4 tabs like so (simplified for sake of brevity):

```
<Tab.Navigator>
  <Tab.Screen name="Feed" component={WebViewNavigator} initialParams={{...}} />
  <Tab.Screen name="Schedule" component={WebViewNavigator} initialParams={{...}} />
  <Tab.Screen name="About" component={WebViewNavigator} initialParams={{...}} />
  <Tab.Screen name="Help" component={WebViewNavigator} initialParams={{...}} />
</Tab.Navigator>
```

The `WebViewNavigator` component is a stack view using a [React Native Webview](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-webview) to load some corresponding web content, however, it does not load until the corresponding tab is activated:

```
<Stack.Navigator>
  <Stack.Screen name="Viewer" component={WebViewScreen} />
</Stack.Navigator>
```

Is there a way to have the app load all tabs/webviews on load so there isn't this webview loading delay on each tab?

I am using the `lazy` prop of [`createBottomTabNavigator`](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/bottom-tab-navigator) which doesn't seem to have any effect:

```
<Tab.Navigator lazy={false}> ...
```

Triggering a log in the `WebView` constructor reveals that the stack navigator is instantiated, but the webview is not loaded.

Comment: I have an issue: lag while switching tab contains webview when app coming from background (first time focus). Did you have this issue?

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to appear in IOS only, Android works fine.

Someone proposed a PR in the `react-native-webview` package solving this particular issue: https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-webview/pull/813

To use it before it's merged, use in your package.json:

```
"react-native-webview": "https://github.com/philippeauriach/react-native-webview#8b7015037d9c1329e4e65e1978e98c4897a928e6",
```

Run `cd ios && pod install`

Comment: The diff for that commit is quite small, but do you know _why_ it works? The conversation on the PR suggests some things fail to work when adopting that approach

Answer (score 0):

with `<Tab.Navigator lazy={false}>` you also need to install webview from patched PR

```
"react-native-webview": "git://github.com/NeilChan/react-native-webview#ab9df38fec002aa7f459498d3d53adb47b3f1f9c",
```

then run `yarn`/`npm install` and  `cd ios && pod install`